# How to flatten these vertices

Tags: modeling

what method can I use to flatten these vertices, some are not even in line if you notice carefully. I tried to to scale in ZYX:0 but its not making them flat along the axis. I also made a new transform orientation to see if the vertices will be flat along the green line, but that doesnt work either.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could fill a face between existing vertices, create a custom orientation, and use it to flatten on Z? Or please share your file

Comment: Here's the file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dsoWo3zd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dsoWo3zd/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select a perpendicular face, create a custom orientation:

[image]

Select the edges and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

This way you are sure that it's perfectly perpendicular:

[image]

Or select the bottom faces and same thing, create a custom orientation and use it to flatten the top of the canon (on Z this time):

[image]

In both cases, if the selected faces are not aligned with the global Y axis the flatten operation won't look completely aligned either, but they will be aligned with the face Y axis.

Comment: Thank you, excellent method!

Comment: well I'm not sure I'm right actually

Comment: You're right, you're scaling along the line perpendicular to the face you want to get in the end (if you wanted to build the face on those vertices at least), and scaling a face along normal flattens it.

Comment: It's just that the selected faces is not necessarily aligned with the global Y axis so the end may still look unaligned, from what I understand

Comment: This method is correct, the vertices are flat all in one angle, this is what I needed.

https://ibb.co/tzyv0Y0

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions:

- [Use bisect tool to draw the line you want to cut at, then delete loose vertices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrlWs.jpg)
- [Add a plane and turn on snapping to snap vertices to the plane with face project on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPCzj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Enable the builtin *Loop Tools* Addon.

In the mesh specials menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) choose *Loop Tools* > Flatten.